# ArcMap used to create?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

How are the symbols created for building footprints to have front door (small angle seen in first picture)? I have attached what I have thus far - want to convert the bottom picture to the top for the footprints that are very close together?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The maps you have shown are most certainly possible to create in either ArcMap or Illustrator, or a combination of both.  Or, they could have been created in another GIS package.  Is there some aspect of the labelling you're unsure how to do in ArcMap? The roads look like they're a polygon layer, and not a centreline.  You might have more success getting answers to your question if you specify in more detail what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question here.  It is the inclusion of two distinct questions that is preventing your question from being re-opened at the moment.

Comment: Understood, I shortened the question.

Comment: Can it be released now?

Answer (score 4):

You can create nice cartographic products with ArcMap with (among others) the following functionalities:

- the [Maplex](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000054000000) labeling engine, gives access to advanced rules for defining the placement of the labels
- turning the labels to [annotations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000m00000001000000), to fine-tune their placement manually
- [cartographic representations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000004m000000), allow to customize the appearance of the features without changing their actual geometry (showing the streets centerlines as polygons, adding a 'circle' at the end of dead-end streets, etc).

Comment: I forgot you could do that with representations.  Nice one.